# What SSL URL should I use for my Azure portal authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication

I want this OIDC AAD authentication to work in My ASP.net framework apps. So, [here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp) the tutorial

I'm stock here :

"7. Add the SSL URL you copied from Visual Studio in step 1 (for example, https://localhost:44368/) in Redirect URI."

I understand that this would work when debugging, but it's time for live deployment. I have absolutely no idea what is the SSL URL I should put in my azure console. And it's probably not "https://localhost:44368/".

I tried to just put "https://nameOfMyWebSite/claims" but it prompt the Microsoft authentication even after a successful authentication, it causes a loop that ask me to authenticate forever, never redirecting in my web site. I authenticated 5 times in a row to be sure something's wrong.

Comment: if your certificate is issued for https://www.mycustomdomain.net, then you should enter `https://www.mycustomdomain.[n]et` without the brackets obv - but comments cant contain this content

Comment: @singhh-msft I will give you feed-back when I have the occasion to try again, thanks for your concern.

Comment: Sure, pls keep me posted. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per tutorial, you are putting `host`: `https://localhost:44368/`, replace it with host
of your prod website domain directly:

```
https://nameOfMyWebSite.azurewebsites.net/
```

Also, do try adding below URL, as it gets auto populated when you create an App Registration on portal:

```
https://nameOfMyWebSite.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback
```

Comment: It actually worked with : https:// nameOfMyWebSite.domain.qc.ca/claims, the actual problem was : it didn't match what was in Azure app Authentication information, there it was still written localhost. My friend forgot to push save button (maybe he assumed some ajax would auto update the thing on losefocus() event, but nah you have to push save really)